# Extend data to int value from string - Retuning no results in extended column

Tags: extend, kql

Hello knowledgeable KQL people,

I am looking to run a comparison against the software version within the `DeviceTvmSoftwareInventory` table in "Defender 365 Advanced Hunting". ALL of the data is retuned as strings, which means I can't run a `<` or `>` (greater than/less than) comparison.
I have attempted to extend the `SoftwareVersion` to an integer, which does extend the results and presents me with an extra column which is an integer - as seen with `getschema` - Unfortunately none of the values are moved across to the new column and each of the items has a null value.

Any assistance is appreciated

```
DeviceTvmSoftwareInventory
    | where SoftwareVendor == "openssl"
    | extend soft_ver = toint(SoftwareVersion)
    | project DeviceId,DeviceName,SoftwareVendor,SoftwareVersion,soft_ver
```

Results retuned with 'getschema'

[getschema_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1OEz.png)

Results retuned with the extend column

[results_returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj1h8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on what type of comparison you want to perform, you could either:

1. use the built-in [`parse_version()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parse-versionfunction), or
2. parse the version parts (major, minor, build, revision) from your input string, and then compare those according to your desired logic

for example:

```
datatable(v:string)
["0.0.0.5","0.0.7.0","0.0.3","0.2","0.1.2.0","1.2.3.4","1","7777.0.0.0"]
| extend parsed = parse_version(v)
| extend parts = split(v, ".")
| extend major = toint(parts[0]), minor = toint(parts[1]), build = toint(parts[2]), revision= toint(parts[3])
| project-away parts
```

| v | parsed | major | minor | build | revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0.0.5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 0.0.7.0 | 700000000 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 0.0.3 | 300000000 | 0 | 0 | 3 |  |
| 0.2 | 20000000000000000 | 0 | 2 |  |  |
| 0.1.2.0 | 10000000200000000 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1.2.3.4 | 1000000020000000300000004 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 1000000000000000000000000 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 7777.0.0.0 | 7777000000000000000000000000 | 7777 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Thanks - Away from my desk - Will give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this - I've learnt something new and have an end result - My "reputation" isn't good enough to cast a vote - If I could, I would.